# Scroll overflow text into view

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I need to scroll some overflowed text into view.

I have trying to animate its text-indent, but I need to animate the correct amount of pixels. How do I calculate that?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wqRcK/5/

I need to only scroll the text into view, not the "total width" like I tried.

As a side question, how do I make the `span.title` respect the 10 pixels padding?

Comment: 200px - span width should give you that amount, or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: This is an interesting effect that could greatly be used for usability reasons. +1 for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set you `span` to `inline-block`,
and animate it to `"-" + ( $(this).width() - $(this).parent().width() ) + "px"`:

```css
div.box span.title { white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var boxwidth = $("div.box").width();
    $("span.title").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            textIndent: "-" + ( $(this).width() - $(this).parent().width() ) + "px"  
        }, 1000);  
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            textIndent: "0"           
        }, 1000);  
      }
    );
});
```

Here it is in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wqRcK/20/

---

**P.S.** Remember to always cache your selectors.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Joseph answer, I added the padding for your side question make the title symetric => http://jsfiddle.net/wqRcK/45/

Aymeric.